# How can I prevent jQuery's $.getJSON from converting my ajax response keys from strings to integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to use a JSON response object that is ordered by email to populate a select box, but JQuery seems to be changing the type of the key from text to integer, thus re-ordering the response object by the now numeric index, screwing up the order of the select box.

So a json response like:

```
{"2":"aaron@mail.com","1":"bernard@mail.com"}
```

after a code similar to:

```
$.getJSON('urlwithjsonresponse.com',function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

outputs an object like this:

```
{1:"bernard@mail.com",2:"aaron@mail.com"}
```

How can I prevent this conversion / reordering?

P.s. this also happens with $.ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things are wrong here.

1) JSON keys are always string. Just because it is written without quotes doesn't make it a number. It just means the key name is "safe", i.e. doesn't contain spaces or other special characters.

2) JSON hash keys absolutely not guaranteed to be in any particular order. If you are expecting them to be, then your expectation is wrong. You should be serializing your data as an array of objects (or strings) instead of a single hash object.

`["bernard@mail.com","aaron@mail.com"]`

or

`[{key:1,value:"bernard@mail.com"},{key:2, value:"aaron@mail.com"}]`

Actually make that three things

3) The output you seeing has nothing to do with jQuery. That is just how `console.log()` serialized hash object you gave to it. Which is valid (see #2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the order is correct after the JSON conversion you should re-index your array in PHP before sending it:

```
$a = [ 2 => "aaron@mail.com", 1 => "bernard@mail.com" ];
$a = array_values( $a );
exit( json_encode( $a ) );
```

This will ensure at least the elements in your object arrive in the same order you sent them in. You'll lose the keys, if you want to keep those you need to add them to your object (in case the index was the ID of the object for instance):

```
$a = [ 
    2 => [ "id" => 2, "email" => "aaron@mail.com" ], 
    1 => [ "id" => 1, "email" => "bernard@mail.com" ]
];
exit( json_encode( array_values( $a ) );
```